# Send Array of Strings to Native Code in Android

Tags: android, android-ndk

I call a function in `C++` from `java`. In `java` I have an array of `Strings` that I want to use in my `C++`-function.

I have in `C++`:

```
 std::string names[6]; // Global variable
 extern "C"
 JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
 Java_com_erikbylow_mycamera3_JNIUtils_updateStandingBoard(JNIEnv *env, jobject type, std::string *names, jint nbrElements){
    memcpy(standingText, names, 6* sizeof(std::string));
    nbrStandText = nbrElements;
}


In `Java`:
public static void updateStanding( String resultArray[]){
    updateStandingBoard(resultArray, resultArray.length);
}
```

What is the simplest way of achieving what I want? When I try this and different variants it either crashes or yields nonsense data.

Comment: are you looking to convert your c++ code to java? im confused by the question?

Comment: No, I use `C++` in android using the `NDK` library. But the `C++`-function is called from `Java` where I have an array of Strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JNI is a primarily a C API, it doesn't know anything about `std::string` as you can validate by calling *javah* on the Java source file contained the native methods declaration.

Also Java isn't C, there is no need to pass the array size as additional parameter.

So your `native void updateStandingBoard(String[] result, int size)` should actually be `native void updateStandingBoard(String[] result)`

With this in mind, the JNI code should be

```
std::vector<std::string> names; // much safer or use std::array as alternative
extern "C"
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_com_erikbylow_mycamera3_JNIUtils_updateStandingBoard(JNIEnv *env, jobject type, jobjectArray names) {
  jint nbrElements = env->GetArrayLength(names);


  // now copy the strings into C++ world
  for (int i = 0; i < nbrElements ; i++) {
       // access the current string element
       jobject elem = env->GetObjectArrayElement(names, i); 
       jsize length = env->GetStringLength(elem);

       // pin it to avoid GC moving it around during the copy
       const jchar *str = env->GetStringChars(elem, nullptr);


       names.push_back(std::string(str, length));

       // make it available again to the VM 
       env->ReleaseStringChars(elem, str);
  }
}
```

This was just for the basic strings, if you are interested in UTF strings, then you should make use of `std::wstring` and the *UTF* variants of the above JNI functions.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am kind of new to `JNI`. Thanks for the nice explanation.